# Prove that quotient space is compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am studying general topology. And this is problem I faced.

**Problem** : Let ~ on $S^1 \times [-1, 1]$ : $(a, b)$~$(c,d)$ iff either $(a, b)=(c,d)$ or $b=d=1$ or $b=d=-1$. Show that $S^1 \times [-1, 1]$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

**My attempt** : Let $g$ : $S^1 \times [-1, 1] \rightarrow S^2$ : $g(cos(\theta), sin(\theta), y)=(\sqrt{1-y^2}cos(\theta),\sqrt{1-y^2}sin(\theta), y) $. Then $g$ is continuous and surjective. which induces a continuous bijection  $f$ : $S^1 \times [-1, 1] /$~ $\rightarrow S^2$.

$S^2$ is obviously Hausdorff. So, if $S^1 \times [-1, 1] /$~ is a compact space, $f$ is a homoemorphism.

But I have trouble proving compactness. How can I show it?

Comment: Hint: Consider the image of a compact under a continuous map.

Answer (score 1):

$S^1$ is compact and $[-1,1]$ is compact, therefore $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ is also compact. Now $S^2$ is Hausdorff being a subspace of a Hausdorff space, hence the map $f: S^1\times [-1,1]\setminus\sim\to S^2$ is continuous bijection and it is a closed map. It is thus a quotient map and since it is an injective quotient map, it will induces a homeomorphism $\tilde{f}: S^1\times [-1,1] \setminus \sim \to S^2$.